# Two versions of the same code return different results

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, state-space, transfer-function

I expect to get the same results when compressing these two MATLAB lines of code into one, but I don't!

Code in 2 lines:

```
[b,a]= butter(2,[0.4 0.6]) % Transfer function coefficients of the filter  
[A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(b,a)  % State-space representation of the filter
```

Code in 1 line:

```
[A,B,C,D]= butter(2,[0.4 0.6]) % State-space representation of the filter
```

**butter :**

- returns the `transfer function coefficients` when `b,a` are Outputs
- returns the `state-space matrices` when `A,B,C,D` are Outputs

**tf2ss :**

- Convert `transfer function filter parameters` to `state-space` form

Comment: And what's happen when you run `[A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(butter(2,[0.4 0.6]))`?

Comment: for `B` I get `[1;0;0;0]` for the first code and `[0.58;0.19;-0.58;-0.19]` for the second

Comment: @famansour what is your MATLAB version? I can reproduce your results in 2018b

Comment: @Karls that is invalid code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri my version is R2018b !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two state-space representations you are obtaining are valid. The state-space representation of a filter is **not unique**. The two give the same results when applied to an input signal.

The likely reason why the two state-space representations are not the same is that they are obtained following different routes:

- In the two-step version of your code, you obtain the *transfer-function* representation and then convert to *state-space*, using [`tf2ss`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/tf2ss.html).
- In the one-step version, [`butter`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) internally obtains the *zero-pole* representation and then converts to *state-space*, using [`zp2ss`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/zp2ss.html) (at least this it what it does in R2018b).

Here is a **check** that they are indeed equivalent.

```
[b,a]= butter(2,[0.4 0.6]);
[A2,B2,C2,D2] = tf2ss(b,a); % 2 steps

[A1,B1,C1,D1]= butter(2,[0.4 0.6]); % 1 step
```

Define an input signal:

```
x = rand(1,100);
```

Create the two [filter objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/dfilt.statespace.html) from their state-space representations:

```
Hd2 = dfilt.statespace(A2,B2,C2,D2);
Hd1 = dfilt.statespace(A1,B1,C1,D1);
```

Obtain the two outputs:

```
y2 = Hd2.filter(x);
y1 = Hd1.filter(x);
```

Compare the outputs. The difference is of the order of `eps`, that is, neglibible:

```
max(abs(y1))
max(abs(y2))
max(abs(y1-y2))

ans =
   0.348561524872161
ans =
   0.348561524872160
ans =
     8.153200337090993e-16
```

You can also **check** that both state-space representations give the same transfer-function representation:

```
[b1,a1] = ss2tf(A1,B1,C1,D1)
[b2,a2] = ss2tf(A2,B2,C2,D2)

b1 =
0.067455273889072   0.000000000000000  -0.134910547778144   0.000000000000000   0.067455273889072
a1 =
1.000000000000000  -0.000000000000001   1.142980502539900  -0.000000000000001   0.412801598096187
b2 =
0.067455273889072   0.000000000000000  -0.134910547778144  -0.000000000000000   0.067455273889072
a2 =
1.000000000000000  -0.000000000000001   1.142980502539899  -0.000000000000002   0.412801598096187
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the line 1 code should be changed to below.

```
[A,B,C,D]= tf2ss(butter(2,[0.4 0.6]));
```

But, this also will not give the desired answer since, trf2ss required two inputs as input parameters. The above code gives only one input, which is a vector with two values. In Matlab, vectors are a separate type of variables, hence will not work as we expect some times.